# does data-ajax="false" affect performance for offline mobile apps built with phone gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

My question is simple. Does ajax transitions matter for local off-line apps? I tested it on real devices without ajax transitions and with ajax transitions. And I did see a a bit of dip in performance on low end android devices. The newer devices did not show any such lag. Can someone tell me how does non ajax transitions (`data-ajax="false"`) affect an offline application built with `phonegap and jquery mobile.`

Comment: `data-ajax=false` disables Ajax, means pages are loaded normally via HTTP. If you want to disable transitions, you can disable it globally on `mobileinit` by setting `$.mobile.defaultTransition = "none";`.

Comment: Omar I know that. My question is does ajax transition really matter in an app built with phonegap build cloud service. As all the resources are locally available on the hardware.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682218/appcache-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile